# How to do page transitions in a popup using jquery?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, popup

We have a web application which uses jquery. We have to add a new module which will open in a popup. Then all the pages in that module will open in the same popup window using ajax.

We will have pages like add/edit/list/search pages. We want the these pages to be loaded in the same popup.

Is this possible to do page transition in popup. We are using spring MVC.

**Edit 1**

Its like you click on a link in a menu, it will open a popup. Popup will have few more buttons which will take to new screens but in same popup. I have used ajax to update a small portion of screen. I used to use divs and spans for this. But how do we replace the entire popup page with completely new page with many html components.

As far as I have used ajax, when you do a remote calls, server side methods return some data object as json in response which can be used in client side to update certain area of page.

Can we return entire page in response from server side?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX can work in two way:

- return json object which is used to update content in page
- return html which is used to replace content in page

If you use AJAX to replace the entire page, then any links inside that page will also need to use AJAX to do the same.

An easier approach might be to use an iframe overlay, which can then have the content act like a normal page.  So links within the iframe will work like normal links, but only updating the iframe area.

Comment: How do I use the Iframes. Initially I will need show a regular jquery popup. Now how do I make links in that page to use iframe in popup?

Comment: I suppose some jquery overlay plugins can be made to use an iframe as there overlay mechanism.  In this case, any links in that overlay would just work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get an entire page using AJAX just by making a request for a standard page. Then you would just be able to do `popup.document.documentElement.innerHTML = newHTML`, where `newHTML` is the HTML returned from the server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, but I'd imagine you would just make a request to a route that usually returned HTML and it would do the same for AJAX, unless Spring actually detects Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

From what i remember from Spring MVC it returns views using ModelAndView, so all you have to do is make each view a separate .JSP then make a controller and setup various GET methods to serve each .JSP ( return the view ).

something like:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/view1" )
    public ModelAndView getView1( Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute( "some attr", "some value" );
        return new ModelAndView( "view1" );
    }

     @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/view2" )
    public ModelAndView getView2( Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute( "some attr", "some value" );
        return new ModelAndView( "view2" );
    }

    (...)

}
```

Then in your popup, just make each menu link call a different view ( using an ajax call to the previously mentioned controller ).

Once you get a successful response just dump the response's html in your container div

```
$("#container").html( response );
```

on a side note, you'll probably have to configure your DispatcherServlet to resolve the views you're returning with ModelAndView.

In principle this should work, my java skills are mediocre at best, still it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For JQuery Point of view you can use .html() to replace html coming from server as most of answer mentioned it.

For Spring MVC: there is a major component that resolve views for spring mvc called view resolver you can check it in spring reference document it is responsible to resolve your view from string or ModelAndView to the presentation layer, which could be JSP,JSL,Velocity,FreeMarker or other presentation framework, then once you return String with view name or ModelAndView contains view name it will be resolved to view framework which in most of cases will generate HTML, but is case you want to return JSON or XML you have to use @ResponseBody which is overriding the view resolver behavior and response with the return of method in body based on converters configured with it which is embedded in

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, it's not really AJAX anymore if you replace the entire popup. A regular javascript that just updates the earlier defined popup-window with a new url would be the only way as i know of to change what's happening at a different window.

That is unless you'd create your 'popup' window as a div within the page, eliminating all kinds of browser security issues (a lot of browsers forbid you change content dynamically in another window). That way you can change the whole content of that div with AJAX. With css the div could be implemented as a tab, or a virtual popup window.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this using JQuery

```
  var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Call to Spring Controller", // Yii mvc would look like /myurl.com/action
      data: Spring controller parameters, // remove if you don't have parameters
      dataType: "html"
   });

   request.done(function(msg) {
         //if you have any elements you want to remove or hide, do it here.
         $("#main").html( msg );
   });
```

With HTML similar to this stuck in your popup page

```
  <div id="main">

  </div>
```

and then after the $.ajax call is complete the div will contain any HTML code that you pass back via spring.

Answer (score 1):

Your controllers could return JSON (but you will need some sort of templating - covered below - ability to fill **just** the values. **Or** have your controllers to return html and replace via javascript the pieces of the page you need.

In your html you could do something like this:

```
<div id='loader'>Loading...</div>
<div id='popup'>This will be replaced</div>
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<secton id='content'></section>
<footer></footer>
```

Be sure to hide these two div's in your css: `div#loader, div#popup { display: none; }`

Set the `z-index` for the loader less than the `z-index` for the popup.

Set a property in your `a` tags to specify whether each should open a popup or not:

```
<a href='your/url' data-pops>Click me</a>
```

Now bind all these anchors click event to a function to handle this:

```
$('a[href]').click(function() {
    var self = this;
    var url = $(self).attr('href');

    if($(self).attr('data-pops')) {
        showPopup(url);
    } else {
        loadContentPartial(url);
    }
});
```

If the `data-pops` attribute is present it will call the `showPopup` function with the specified url from the anchor. Otherwise it will perform a call to a function named `loadContentPartial` here you can update your content.

Your `showPopup` function could perform these tasks:

- Show the loader.
- Perform a `$.get`.

  - If your get returns only json (i recommend you use knockoutjs - an mvvm framework)
  - If your get returns raw html: When the get is done, replace the content of the popup div for the content returned from the `$.get`.
- DO NOT HIDE the loader and show the popup. (the loader image/icon/text won't be visible because the popup will be over it - keeping the grayed overlay to avoid user interaction)

Your `loadContentPartial` function should perform almost the same tasks as your show popup with the difference it should replace your section content then hide the loader.
**NOTE** a bit of a *cheat* here you could perform an entire page request, and here replace the content returned into your current page content, your requests will be a bit bigger, but nowadays returning 30k or 10k it's not that critical, if you're not Facebook, of course.

Now: You could write your html from the controllers, or even better write some helper methods to generate raw html to return, with the form, buttons, fields and everything you might need. If you chose to use knockout js, there are several tutorials around, here is the best tutorial for me recorded at [NDC (Norwegian Developer Conference) by Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/07/webstack-of-love.html). It's very easy to use, learn and implement. You could take a look at `Handlebarsjs` called itself as *Minimal templating with steroids*, I've never used it but here is the [link](http://handlebarsjs.com), K Scott Allen has a great tutorial (as usual) in Pluralsight called [ASP.NET MVC4 Fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4).

If by any chance you need a loader for the popup you could do one of these things:

- Change the `z-index` of the overlayed loader, then change it back when the popup has finished processing.
- Create another overlayed loader such as `div#popupLoader` and set a `z-index` higher than the `div#popup`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the same problem in our application is concerned , we used a fancybox plugin for Jquery.
In which, you just have to send the json encoded data if you want to display just the HTML.
[You can download it from here](http://code.google.com/p/wp-fancybox/source/browse/trunk/jquery.fancybox.js?r=6).
You can also pass the URLs that you want to display in the popup/fancybox. It can act just like you another web page where you can access other links to the web also.

All you have to do is add a class "fancybox fancybox.iframe" to the HTML tag where you want to display the popup and the link.

Here is an example for the same:

```
<div class="question"><a class="upload_link fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://localhost/4.0/utils/info/cust_id"></a></div>
```